# Как сделать так, что бы строка ax.plot(x, y, label="y = ax^2+bx+c") выводила вместо a, b, c введённые числа

Tags: python

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import (MultipleLocator, FormatStrFormatter, AutoMinorLocator)

import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 5000)

print ('Введите а')
a=float(input())
print ('Введите b')
b=float(input())
print ('Введите c')
c=float(input())
y=a*x*x + b*x + c  

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
ax.set_title("Графики квадратичной функции: y=ax^2+bx+c", fontsize=16)
ax.set_xlabel("x", fontsize=14)        
ax.set_ylabel("y", fontsize=14)
ax.grid(which="major", linewidth=1.2)
ax.grid(which="minor", linestyle="--", color="black", linewidth=0.5)
ax.plot(x, y, label="y = ax^2+bx+c")
ax.legend()
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator())
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator())
ax.tick_params(which='major', length=10, width=2)
ax.tick_params(which='minor', length=5, width=1)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подставьте их

```
ax.set_title("Графики квадратичной функции: y = {}x^2+{}x+{}".format(a,b,c), fontsize=16)
```

и сюда

```
ax.plot(x, y, label="y = {}x^2+{}x+{}".format(a,b,c))
```